# Cartoon where the main character had a cannon built into his arm?

Tags: story-identification, character-identification

When I was a kid, about 23 years ago I remember I was watching a cartoon where the main character had a cannon built in to his arm. So when everything got hairy, he just screwed his arm off, and this hand-cannon was ready to fire.

I can't remember anything about the plot. I have a vague memory of him having a black t-shirt and blond hair.

Comment: Was it... Mega Man?

Answer (score 17):

The answer is *[Space Adventure Cobra](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0163494/)*!

[image]

Comment: You should probably select your answer.

Comment: @MarkRogers, Self answers can only be accepted after 48 hours.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  Now it would be nice if an answer is selected, however.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for [Mega Man (1994)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man_(TV_series)).

[image]

The main character "Mega Man" possessed a cannon built into his arm. When not in combat he had a hand at the end of his arm, but would retract his hand and use his cannon in combat.

While he doesn't have blond hair, his sister, Roll did. She also had a similar hand cannon attachment, but her cannon tended to be limited to household tools (broom, vacuum, plunger, etc).

[image]

Another Prominant character was Protoman. Mostly a villian, but he also had a cannon arm similar to Mega Man's, he had a grey torso (not black, but close), and wore a yellow scarf.

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Im very greatfull for your answer! But im afraid thats not the one. It was much more He-Man drawn. (sorry for not knowing the terminology). He littrearly pulled of his own "human" forearm and underneath there was a black cannon. Thank you so much anyway!

Comment: @marcusfromsweden - Are you sure you aren't thinking of the character [Bass](https://www.google.com/search?q=mega+man+bass&biw=1680&bih=939&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAmoVChMIl4383ML3xwIVgnuSCh0QMgLk) from megaman?

Comment: I found it ! Space Adventure Cobra! My mind played a trick on me! Hes shirt was red.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6e7tEFTibI

Comment: Mega Man X features blond-haired, red-armored [Zero with an arm cannon](http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Buster).

Comment: Aaaaaah, nothing says equality Iike a female cyborg whose attachments are limited to cooking and cleaning.