# Anime show featuring a blue boy with arm cannon

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember a few years ago, I watched a little bit of an anime where the main character was a boy in blue with an arm cannon. I recall the talking blue arm cannon as being a wolf's head, though that might not be correct. I know it was some kind of animal head (note: cannon might also have not talked, but it was definitely an animal head).

I've been thinking about checking the shows Toonami used to air but I can't find a collection of their shows. That might be a good place to start looking.

---

It's not  ["Space Adventure Cobra!"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102836/cartoon-where-the-main-character-had-a-cannon-built-into-his-arm), nor is it Mega-Man (unless there's a version of mega man that has a talking arm cannon)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102836/cartoon-where-the-main-character-had-a-cannon-built-into-his-arm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartoon where the main character had a cannon built into his arm?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102836/cartoon-where-the-main-character-had-a-cannon-built-into-his-arm)

Comment: @TimSparrow - Unless OP confirms that it's the same property, our [policy is to leave it open](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Toonami) a list of Toonami shows.

Answer (score 12):

> "nor is it Mega-Man (unless there's a version of mega man that has a talking arm cannon)"

There is indeed. In [Mega Man Star Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man_Star_Force_(anime)), the protagonist merges with a wolf-like entity, an "electromagnetic being" named Omega-Xis, to become this series' version of Mega Man, in the form of an "EM Wave Human". When they are merged together, Omega-Xis resides in the wolf-head-shaped gauntlet/cannon on Mega Man's arm, and frequently talks to the protagonist:

[image: An animated GIF depicting Megaman seemingly talking to his cannon, which is shaped like a robot wolf. The "wolf" has red eyes and glowing spiky green hairs. The pattern on its head also matches the one on Megaman's helmet: an hexagon with a bottom pointing arrow.]
[image: Another GIF depicting Megaman talking as he was inspecting his right arm. Suddenly, his left arm was lifted up to show us the sentient wolf-like cannon talking. Whether Megaman lifted his arm himself or if it was lifted by the sentient cannon is left open for interpretation. The glowing green hair behind the "wolf" is reminiscent of the flames bursting out from behind a missile.]

Comment: So, this is what happens if your writer's room accidentally eat a whole bunch of magic mushrooms on 'pitch day'