Sci-fi anime in which a main character had a robotic-looking arm and was in a war or part of a rebellion
I remember, vaguely, watching an anime where a main character had a robotic-looking arm that was orange and was in a war or part of a rebellion. Other characters also have mechanical enhancements, I believe.
Just want to look it up and see if the show is any good. Unfortunately, these are the only details I can remember.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Was it a movie or a series? And did you watch it on TV or online?

We've got a few stories on here about anime/cartoon characters with robotic arms, at least three in the Related sidebar. I suspect the orange part might be the only distinguishing feature so far.

Actually, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254501/anime-or-cartoon-where-one-of-the-main-characters-had-a-robotic-cyborg-arm-and-w?rq=1 is red, tending towards orange.

Early 2000s ot was a show on tv maybe toonami or adult swim late noght tv. His fighting abolities had stages or gears to it and when he fought his arm would emite "flames" and maybe have floating orbs with spikes on them that could also emite a small non- combative flame. Maybe it even developed concentric semi circles around it in either early or later stages. For sure fighting a war or a rebellion. Sorry for the trickle info. I have had many concussion since watching it to today
